# How can I override default "global" keyboard shortcuts and create my own instead?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, keyboard-shortcuts

I understand basic event routing/bubbling in WPF (apparently not enough, though)... what I'm trying to do is have basic keyboard shortcuts that make sense in my WPF desktop application. For example, I have a ListBox, and when the user presses <kbd>Page-Up</kbd> or <kbd>Page-Down</kbd> (anything could be focused in the application), I want the list box to select its previous or next item, if applicable.

This is what I have so far, but it doesn't work. This is the constructor for a window called "Main":

```
public Main()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Initialize keyboard shortcuts
    KeyDown += (s, e) =>
    {
        var viewModel = GetActiveViewModel();
        if (e.Key == Key.PageUp)
        {
            viewModel.SelectPreviousItem();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else if (e.Key == Key.PageDown)
        {
            viewModel.SelectNextItem();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    };
}
```

Instead of this code working, the active control is "stealing" the event and implementing the default behavior, e.g. if I have a text box selected, the text box is moving the cursor, and if I have the list box selected, the list box is moving the selected index one "page", instead of a single item like I want.

How can I instruct WPF to "ignore" any default keyboard hooks and replace them with my own logic instead? I understand that I'm going to be "overriding" the default behavior of some controls (e.g. <kbd>Page-Up</kbd>/<kbd>Page-Down</kbd> in a text box will no longer move the cursor) and that's okay, that's what I want.

Comment: Always remember the principle of least surprise. If I press the "page up" button in an application, and it moves up one item, I'm going to be confused and annoyed. I pressed page up because I wanted to go up a page.

Comment: These aren't my requirements, they are requirements for a business application. I understand UX principles, but I need to implement this. If it makes you feel better, pretend the shortcut is going to be `Ctrl+PageUp` instead. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you can do is register to the **PreviewKeyDown** event.

What happeneds in WPF is that each of the controls can have a default implementation of the event and then set the "Handled" property to true, which tells the visual tree in WPF to stop propagating the event.

Try this:

```
PreviewKeyDown += (s, e) =>
{
   var viewModel = GetActiveViewModel();
   if (e.Key == Key.PageUp)
   {
      viewModel.SelectPreviousItem();
      e.Handled = true;
   }
   else if (e.Key == Key.PageDown)
   {
      viewModel.SelectNextItem();
      e.Handled = true;
   }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

That won't work entirely.

You will need to tunnel through for the OS registered global hotkeys found in the list [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_keyboard_shortcuts):

Hook Win32 OS code using KEYBOARD_LL

SetWindowsHookEx((int) HookType.WH_KEYBOARD_LL, _keyboardProc, moduleHandler, 0);

I did this for a company where I wrapped WPF CommandBindings -> WF -> Win32 LL.

A few of the biggest ones like Ctl+Alt+Del you can take out of the registry and remove all the options in the screen like Logoff, Task Manager, etc.